# Finding all word with a specific letter in a string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, find, letter

I need to find out how to output all the word that *contain* `"a"`. I have a `string` with all the months and want to output the ones that *contain* `"a"` to *console*.
Here´s what i have so far

```
string[] Månedsdage = { 
  "Januar", "Februar", "Marts", 
  "April", "Maj", "Juni", 
  "juli", "August", "September", 
  "Oktober", "November", "December", 
  "Bichat" };

for (int i = 0; i < Månedsdage.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Månedsdage[i].Length; j++)
    {
        if (Månedsdage[i].Substring(j,1) == "a")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Alle måneder med A: ");
            Console.WriteLine(Månedsdage[j]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [String.Contains Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Enumerable.Where Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 6):

What about this

```
string[] result = Månedsdage.Where(x=> x.ToLower().Contains('a')).ToArray();
```

[.Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) : To get all words containing letter `a` we used string method. This extension method checks whether a substring passed as a parameter is exist in given string or not.

[Where()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) : To apply same condition on each element from string array, we used Linq extension method.

[ToLower()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=netframework-4.7.2) : This method is used to make all characters of string in lower case. So it will not miss 'A' and 'a'. `ToLower()` will include `April` in resultant array. If you don't want `April` to be in your array, do not use `ToLower()`

POC: [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Biywj3)

Output:

```
Januar
Februar
Marts
April  /*ToLower() ;)*/
Maj
August
Bichat
```

Comment: I would be a good answer if you added the appropriate documentation and explain the answer a little so future readers learn something apposed to  just a one line code answer

Comment: Also `Where` is not going to return an `array`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `Contains` *doesn't accept* `StringComparison`, but `IndexOf` does: we can try filtering out these `word`s where `"a"`th index is *not negative* (i.e. `"a"` appears in the `word`)

```
    string[] Månedsdage = { 
      "Januar", "Februar", "Marts", 
      "April", "Maj", "Juni", 
      "juli", "August", "September", 
      "Oktober", "November", "December", 
      "Bichat" };

    // StringComparison.CurrentCulture if you want case sensitive search
    var result = Månedsdage
      .Where(word => word.IndexOf("a", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);

    Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output:

```
Januar
Februar
Marts
April
Maj
August
Bichat
```